# Copy colunm values by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes such as below:

df1:

```
id   value
2     100
5     120
9     300
10    500
```

df2:

```
id   value
2    200
3    120
5    500
8    123
4    2000
```

I need to update "df1" value from df2, only when id matches.

so the reult is:

df1

```
id   value
2    200
5    120
9    500
10   500
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question to show what you’ve tried / researched on your own so far.  Thanks.

Comment: Please use code formatting for your data blocks, they will be much easier to read. Don't format your questions with blank lines.

Comment: Shouldn’t ID 5 be 500 in the result?  And ID 9 be 300?

Comment: @S3DEV YES you are right! Any idea please?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Close.. but what i am looking for is a "replace" insteand of creating a new column.

Comment: @PYDater - S3DEV corrected the expected output for you. Can you edit your question so its solvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way -

```
df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['value']).fillna(df1['value'])
```

**Output**

```
0    200.0
1    500.0
2    300.0
3    500.0
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

For replacing, you can set

```
df1['value'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['value']).fillna(df1['value'])
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek! The second part is the correct answer.